# Read a string from parallel port using C#

Tags: c#, parallel-port

I was able to write a string into LPT1 using following code:

```
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

            static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, FileAccess dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

            Byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
            buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

            SafeFileHandle fh = CreateFile("LPT1:", FileAccess.Write, 0, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (!fh.IsInvalid)
            {
                FileStream lpt1 = new FileStream(fh, FileAccess.Write);
                lpt1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                lpt1.Close();
            }
```

Since the port is virtual I can check that the string is written in attached file. The question is: how do I read a string from LPT1 without accesing attached file? I've tried to use the same approach but changing method to `lpt1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` and changing to `FileAccess.Read`mode. It throws me an exception `Incorrect function`.